# How to strike through input text when checkbox is ticked?

Tags: html, css

Thanks to another user's question here I was able to strike through the text when the checkbox next to it is ticked, thanks to the following HTML and CSS:

```
<style>
    /* Customize the label (the container) */
    .container {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 18px;
    }
    /* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
    .container input {
    display: none
    }
    /* Create a custom checkbox - using ::before */
    .checkmark::before {
    content: "";
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: solid 2px #194263;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    }
    /* Show the checkmark when checked */
    .container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
    display: block;
    left: 9px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 14px;
    border: solid #194263;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 10px;
    }
    /* strike through the text */
    .container input:checked~.checkmark {
    text-decoration: line-through
    }
</style>
<label class="container">
<input type="checkbox">
<span class="checkmark"></span><br> 
</label>
```

Now, I'd like to let a user add their own text, and still strike through it when the checkbox is ticked. Adding an input field within the span tag as follows does not work.

```
<label class="container">
<input type="checkbox">
<span class="checkmark"><input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="100" size="60%" placeholder="Add an item"></span><br>   
</label>
```

Why does this not work? What to do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has the following issue. When you write these lines of css:

```css
    .container input:checked~.checkmark {
    text-decoration: line-through
    }
```

You're not adding the `text-decoration: line-through` css property to the text `input` element you want to strike, but to the checkmark instead. Therefore, the text input element is not receiving any strike-through styles.

What I did to solve your problem was adding the styles to the text input. I did this by doing some small changes to your HTML and CSS, this is the code:

```css
    /* Customize the label (the container) */
    .container {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 18px;
    }
    /* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
    .container input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none
    }
    /* Create a custom checkbox - using ::before */
    .checkmark::before {
    content: "";
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: solid 2px #194263;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    }
    /* Show the checkmark when checked */
    .container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
    display: block;
    left: 9px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 14px;
    border: solid #194263;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 10px;
    }
    /* strike through the text */
    .container input:checked ~ input {
      text-decoration: line-through
    }
```

```html
<label class="container">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="100" size="60%" placeholder="Add an item">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
  <br>   
</label>
```

And this is the result:
[image: Checkbox with strike-through text]